# Lombok not creating default constructor causing jackson-databinding to fail

Tags: java, jackson, lombok, jackson-databind

I have a POJO

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstrcutor
class Test {

T field1,
T field2,
}
```

When I am trying to deserialize it with jackson-databind 2.9.3,it is

> failing com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException:
>   Cannot construct instance of `com.mypackage.Test` (no Creators, like
>   default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no
>   delegate- or property-based Creator)  at [Source: (String)

Comment: You have to use @NoArgsConstructor annotation as well on the top of your class.

Comment: This was working fine before I upgraded lombok to 1.16.22

Comment: @Sakalya, try with lombok latest version 1.18.2, should work fine in case if there is a bug in 1.16.22. Also, it is backward compatible, so do not worry.

Answer (score 3):

`@AllArgsConstructor` creates a constructor with an argument for each field of the class (so, in your case, you'll get `Test(T, T)`).

For a default constructor, you should add the `@NoArgsConstructor` annotation:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstrcutor // Won't be used by Jackson, but there's no harm in it, per-se
@NoArgsConstructor // Here!
class Test {
    T field1;
    T field2;
}
```

Comment: This was working fine before I upgraded lombok to 1.16.22

Answer (score -1):

Of course `Lombok` doesn't generate a default constructor.

With: `@AllArgsConstrcutor` you say you want it to generate a constructor with all the parameters provided.
Since a POJO on it's own only needs one constructor, that 'll be it.

If you want a default constructor to be generated, add this: `@NoArgsConstructor`

Comment: This was working fine before I upgraded lombok to 1.16.22

Comment: @Sakalya no, it didn't. Seeing as you misspelled "AllArgsConstructor", your code wouldn't even compile, let alone run and generate constructors it's not supposed to. That's also not the only issue in that Java file that prevents compilation.

Comment: Its just a typing mistake